# XSLT show a base64 as a image

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have XML with a node containing a base64 format image.
I've tried a lot of things but I can't generate a PDF with xslt-fo (apache).

This is my XML node to show:

```
.....
<pregunta101>
    <listaImagenes>
        <contenido>base64content</contenido>
        <ruta>c:\\ssss\\aaaa.jpg</ruta>
        <nombre>codigoFOTO</nombre>
    </listaImagenes>
    <listaImagenes>
.....
```

If I put the content instead of "contenido" variable, it shows it perfectly but I can't show it inside a foreach or directly read the xml node.

```
<fo:table-row number-columns-spanned="2">
    <fo:table-cell padding-right="10pt" padding-top="10pt" padding-left="10pt">
        <xsl:for-each select="solicitude/preguntasCheckList/pregunta101/listaImagenes">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <fo:block text-align="left">
                <fo:external-graphic src="url('data:image/jpeg;base64,contenido)"/>                                             
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Comment: Please don't post a solution in your question. Create a new answer to your own question if you feel your solution differs to one already posted and would be of use to other people.

Comment: Sorry for that. The next time i do this.

Comment: I have reverted your post to @Arkanon's first edit. That's how it should be. Arkanon improved the grammar and indenting. And, as Arkanon already said; you should not post your answer in the question. *Please do not enter them again*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only tested with an online XML-FO Processor, but it should work if you change

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('data:image/jpeg;base64,contenido)"/>
```

into

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('data:image/jpeg;base64,{contenido})"/>
```

With this adjustment I get for your example XML as input

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('data:image/jpeg;base64,base64content)"/>
```

If you don't put the node/variable name into curly braces -  `{}`, it will just be handled as literal value instead of being interpreted.

For reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates