# Show an image in a pdf generated from a xsl

Tags: java, image, pdf, xls

I am trying to pass a 64 base image to my xsl via parameters.
based in this question ([XSLT show a base64 as a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025988/xslt-show-a-base64-as-a-image)) I wrote:

```
 <fo:external-graphic src="data:image/png;base64,$sign_2"/>
```

and any image is output (to a PDF)

I also tried

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('data:image/png;base64,$sign_2')"/>
```

with same results!!! (No image output in my pdf)

Any hint for this ?

TIA,
Yamil

Comment: `<xsl:param name="sign_2" />` exists?

Comment: You want {$sign_2}